# Component L2 of the Raspberry Pi camera broken - how can I repair it?

Tags: pi-3, camera

I'm so sad..
The component labeled L2 of the Raspberry Pi camera is broken. What can I do to use the camera again? Is there a way to either repair it or use the camera without it?

[image]

Comment: Try calling the FBI above, maybe they can disable it for you ;)

Comment: Have you tried to bridge the component?

Comment: So rude for a russian @Dmitry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the component marked L2 is not an L2 cache, that is a CPU specific concept; rather it is an inductor. I am unable to locate the schematic for the camera board to identify a specific part number. However, even if you can find the correct part, you would still need to have the skill and tools needed to solder a very small SMD component.

I think you may have to pronounce your camera dead and purchase a replacement. I would suggest getting a case that would help prevent a repeat accident.

Answer (score 1):

As [Steve](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/69893/19949) has already pointed out that the respective component L2 is an inductor. From the wiring it is rather obvious that this is a component that contains two coils with two pins each.

[Hackaday](https://hackaday.io/project/19480-raspberry-pi-camera-v21-reversed) claims that this is a so called common mode choke.

> Thomas wrote 01/17/2017 at 08:23
>
> Just guessing: filters to improve noise immunity by flattening out spikes on one line while coupling it to the other? This would improve common mode rejection at a differential input, and it's standard practice for CAN networks.
>
> Mike wrote 01/18/2017 at 14:32
>
> Thomas was correct in that the filters are common mode chokes used on the mipi diff pairs for noise rejection.  This is standard practice in smartphones.  The I2C memory is usually used to store camera tuning information.  This is unique to each camera module and is programmmed at the factory.

If that is true (and I rather believe it to be so) and this choke acts as a filter only it *might* even work without it (*might* as in: it might work and it might not, it might work in one environment and fail in a more noisy setting). In this case one could try to brigde the respective pads - those directly opposing each other (check this with L3 or L4 that still remain) - with a very thin wire.

Obviously, Steve's hint still applies concerning the skills and tools needed to solder such a small thing. There is however - as with all tinkering - the chance to completely ruin it or even damage the connected Pi.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my 2 cents. 
I've been looking into the feasibility of repairing my camera modules, with the idea that if they are repairable, they are worth having in my project (vs getting a more expensive, but more durable camera)

Here are links to a project which has been looking into reverse engineering the board.
https://github.com/DrYerzinia/RaspberryPiCamerav21

https://hackaday.io/project/19480-raspberry-pi-camera-v21-reversed