# Missing L4 chip near HDMI port, not boot up and usb port no power output

Tags: pi-2, hdmi, usb-power

My rpi work perfectly until I touch it, It not boot up then I found the L4 chip HDMI port is missing(I have touched HDMI port I think my fingernail pull it off...).

I found that tiny chip in the box tried to soil it back but no luck.(the board seems fine but the chip left 1 foot on board), I have checked no more chip missing.

Solid red + green light with/without sd card, no Video output and the usb port no power output.
(green blink once after power connect)

I want to find what l4 is and try to replace a new one.

may have other reason make the device fail to boot.
I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B.

[image]

Comment: No markings on that mosfet?

Comment: No markings on each side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L4 through L7 appear to be surface-mount [common-mode choke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choke_(electronics)#Common-mode_(CM)_chokes)s on the HDMI output's TMDS pairs. It may also be possible to bypass a missing choke by bridging each processor-side pad (right side of photo in question) to its corresponding connector-side pad (left) with thin wire or component lead trimmings, at the expense of the HDMI output being less reliable and more likely to cause radio-frequency interference.

Missing or broken HDMI chokes shouldn't prevent the board from booting or generating composite (analog) video, but if an HDMI display is connected at power-on it might still detect it and try to use HDMI instead of enabling the composite output.

Comment: Very interesting, learned something new. Here’s a question about a common mode choke missing on the Rpi camera module. It has some good additional information: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/69892/component-l2-of-the-raspberry-pi-camera-broken-how-can-i-repair-it